# How to disable finder folder metadata persistence?

Tags: finder, folders, metadata

Is there a way to tell finder not to save any metadata about folders?

I would love to get Finder to forget how it displayed any folder the last time I viewed it.
So when expanding a folder it does not expand the whole subtree I opened last time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Death to DS_Store](https://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/).

The [source code](https://github.com/snielsen/DeathToDSStore) is available on GitHub and the [binary](http://www.aorensoftware.com/Downloads/Files/DeathToDSStore.zip) is available as well.

Comment: Does it stop the finder from remembering the expand/collapse status of folders?

Comment: Yes, as this state is saved in the .DS_Store file as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do the trick. The expanded/collapsed state is not persisted throughout system reboots, but during a session the folders stay expanded/collapsed. So this state is probably saved somewhere else too, not just the .DS_Store files.

Comment: Please let us know what version of OS X/macOS you are using.

Comment: Using OSX 10.11. I have diabled SIP. DeathToDSStore is installed succesful and has a launch agent, so yes, even after rebooting no .DS_Store files reappeared, and i dont have any .DS_Store files left on my device which i removed with:
`sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;`